# IllegalLocationConstraintException whilst creating an S3 bucket in CFN resource provider test

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm creating a Cloudformation Resource Provider using the cloudformation cli.  When I try to test my resource locally using `cfn test` I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (IllegalLocationConstraintException) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The us-east-2 location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.
```

My code looks as follows:

```
s3 = session.client("s3")
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket123',CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'})
```

I've also tried other regions and have tried without the LocationConstraint and I get the same error with the word `undefined` where the region code is:

```
s3 = session.client("s3")
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket123')
```

`cfn test` actually runs the code within sam local using `sam local start-lambda` so I'm a bit perplexed as to why I would even need a region here?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `client` must also be set to the region you want:

```
s3 = session.client("s3", region_name='us-east-2')
s3.create_bucket(Bucket='mybucket123',CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'})
```

Comment: bingo!  that worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add and override location constraints.
Copying s3 bucket files to local example

By using AWS CLI: (configuration required)

```
aws s3 sync --region <request-bucket-region> --source-region <default- 
region> s3://<bucket-name>/<path-if-specific> ~/<local-machine-directory>
```